# scala InputStreamReader Not reading entire data (file)

Tags: java, scala, rest, http

i am trying to hit tally server via scala rest call and save output in file

when i curl same i get around 412K line of output
but when i hit via scala i get only 411K lines (around 500 lines are missing)

is this because of some buffer size issue

following is my code

```
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(b.length))
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST")
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true)
    httpConn.setDoInput(true)
    val out = httpConn.getOutputStream
    out.write(b)
    out.close()
    val isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream)
    val in = new BufferedReader(isr) 
    var temp: String = null
    temp= SaveFile(in)  //pass stream to save into file
```

and file is save via

```
 def SaveFile(a: BufferedReader): String = { 
    val file = new File("OPinWorkspace.xml")
    val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))


    Iterator 
    .continually (a.read)
    .takeWhile (-1 !=)
    .foreach (bw.write)


return foo
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close%28%29) your streams when done.

`close` flushes the stream first.

```
try { 
    // ...
} finally {
    a.close
    if(bw != null) bw.close     // close and flush
}
```